# Looking for the name of a paperback trilogy about teenage post apocalyptic survival from the '90s. It had thunder in the title

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Teenage boy has to find a place with survivors in post apocalyptic world. Pretty sure it started like that. On his journey meets a girl and they fall in love. Reminds me of the *Fallout* video game series kind of story. I remember this from the mid '90s. Was one of my favorite series and would love to re-read for nostalgic reasons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: How does he meet the other survivors?  Is he alone at the start and meets them gradually?  Does a group come to him?  How post-apocalyptic was it?  Did they have to scavenge for food, or was it possible to live off the land?

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 6):

This probably isn't right, but possibly Patrick Tilley's Amtrak Wars series?

Pros:

- post apocalypse
- teenage boy looking for survivors
- meets and falls in love with girl
- one of the books was called "Earth Thunder"

Cons:

- six books, rather than a trilogy
- the boy IS looking for survivors, but the intent is to kill them
- he's also not alone, but part of a large expedition

Comment: Yes! Spot on! Thanks man!

Comment: @user145766 cool! It's nice when a long shot hits the mark. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick above.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the [Firebrats](https://www.goodreads.com/series/68048-firebrats) series by Barbara and Scott Siegel:

> Fire Brats is a series set in the aftermath of World War 3, it follows the struggles of two teenagers Matt and Dani to escape a nuclear-bombed city and find a new life.
>
> Matt and Dani scarcely know one another when World War 3 happens. They meet each other in a theater basement, where they live on junk food and suffer a mild form of radiation sickness.
>
> When an earthquake destroys the building over their heads a month later, they dig their way out to find themselves threatened by a gang of escaped convicts. They escape to head for California, where Matt hopes to find the rest of his family still alive.

The description and date fit, and the third book is [Thunder Mountain](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1272386.Thunder_Mountain), which fits your description of having "Thunder" in the title.